# List all viewflow processes the user is allowed to

Tags: django-viewflow

I'm trying to implement `django-viewflow` in my project, using `django-admin` as a **GUI**.

I'm currently trying to create a **custom view** and **relative template** to show a user a list of all the processes that he can start,
so not the process instances but a list of process models he's allowed to see.

Is it possible? I tried using the `ProcessListView` but it requires a `flow_class`, while I'd like to see **all flows the user is allowed to**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get available process instances with `Process.objects.filter_available([flow_class1, flow_class2, ...], user)`

Comment: Any way not to list up flow_class 1,2,3 to allowed flows for the user?

Comment: Viewflow all built around "Explicit better than implicit" concept